# How to push an array field value if that array field value dont exist in database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have this function on my backend:

```
exports.updatePacienteByCodigo = function (req, res) {
let codPaciente = req.params.codPaciente;
let params = req.body; // This is the data what come from frontend = {'testRealizados':['example'], 'respuestas':['example'], 'codMedico':'example'}
Paciente.findOneAndUpdate({ codPaciente: codPaciente }, {
    '$push': {
        'testsRealizados': params.testsRealizados,
        'respuestas': params.respuestas,
        'codMedico': {'$ne':params.codMedico} //here is the problem
    }
}).then(
    pacienteEncontrado => {
        if (!pacienteEncontrado) {
            res.status(404).send({ accion: 'updatePaciente', mensaje: 'Ese paciente no existe' });
        } else {
            res.status(200).send({ accion: 'updatePaciente', mensaje: 'Paciente actualizado correctamente' });
        }
    }
).catch(err => { res.status(500).send({ accion: 'updatePaciente', mensaje: 'Error ' + err }) })
};
```

This query throw me this error `"Error CastError: Cast to [string] failed for value \"[{\"$ne\":\"o8qjdeli\"}]\" at path \"codMedico\""}`

What I want to do is, if `codMedico` have the same value in the database than the param codMedico dont update that field.

I tried that but that didnt work. I am out of ideas so here I am. Thanks.

## [SOLVED]

I tried with $addToSet method and it works perfectly like @Plancke told me in the comments.

Comment: You're applying a comparison query operator inside an update. We'd really need to see your data to be able to help you further. Please also check out the $addToSet operator, that might be what you're looking for instead of $push.

Comment: $addToSet works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with $addToSet method and it works perfectly like @Plancke told me in the comments.